# Still can't import after install numpy in TensorFlow tutorial

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

[This is how I setted up my python3 envirnoment on Ubuntu 16.04.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04)

And I installed TensorFlow 0.8 with Virtualenv installation.

[As I wanted to start TensorFlow tutorial MNIST For ML Beginners the The MNIST Data part.](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#the-mnist-data)

This is the way I did it

```
$ cd environments
~/environments$ pyvenv my_env
~/environments$ ls my_env
bin  include  lib  lib64  pyvenv.cfg  share
~/environments$ source my_env/bin/activate
(my_env) :~/environments$ nano input_data.py
(my_env) :~/environments$ python input_data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input_data.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

The input_data.py is from Github tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py.

So I installed numpy with

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

But I still got the same output.

Maybe there's something wrong with my installation or I use the wrong way with Python.

I have stucked for days and need your help.

I had upgraded TensorFlow to 0.11 version.

I will try again later.

Comment: Does "python" point to python3 or python2? Usually it's the latter, so you may just need to use "python3 input_data.py".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the very late update, I had update tensorflow to the latest version.

And I think I had some mistakes back then.

Since I install the tensorflow via Virtualenv installation, so I should load tensorflow and other packages in Virtualenv environment.

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

Then run the exist python code by

```
python3 filename.py
```

or directly type

```
python3
```

even

```
ipython3
```

to write your own code, and test with

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It shouldn't have any error messages, unless you are using the GPU support version, add path by type

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

open the bash profile and add

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
```

inside the file,aware this the default path for your cuda,then the last step.

```
source /.bash_profile
```

The ubuntu 16.04 really annoying sometimes.

And thanks for your reponses.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with PIP using

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy==1.11.1
```

or in your case use pip3 instead of pip for python 3 like

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install numpy==1.11.1
```

this will help

Comment: It seemed I have numpy 1.11.2 already then I had the same result.

Comment: which version of tensorflow you are using? and also you need exact version of numpy using which tensorflow module is compiled. For mine 1.11.1 is worked

Comment: I am using tensorflow 0.8

Comment: can you try numpy==1.11.0 ? It seems that TF 0.8 is either compiled with numpy 1.11.0 or 1.11.1

Comment: just got the same output

Comment: can you upgrade tensorflow as current latest version is 0.11 it may solve your problem?

Comment: you are installing numpy in virtual environment correct?

Comment: that's right.I am still finding the way to upgrade tensorflow

Comment: I will try tensorflow 0.11 later

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first installing [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#linux-install) (or miniconda) and installing with conda. Then you will all python dependencies taken care of automatically! The downside with installing with Anaconda is that there is no GPU support (yet). But if you're fine running on CPU then I think Anaconda is by far the easiest way to instal TensorFlow.